# Accidentally ran chmod +x /* - How bad did I just mess up?

Tags: linux, permissions, executable, chmod

I wanted to mark all of the files in the directory I was in as executable, and I ran `chmod +x /*` because I thought that was the command to mark all the files in the directory you were currently in as executable.

Did I mess up? I don't remember what the file permissions looked like beforehand. I didn't use `sudo`.

Comment: Especially since you didn't run it with root permissions (e.g. `sudo`), I think you should be fine. Especially since you (luckily) avoided using the recursive flag `-r`, so only the directories on `/` were affected

Comment: What distro are you using?

Comment: Far less trouble than I had many years back when I ended up running – thanks to a misspelled variable name – `chmod -x /bin`. The primary problem being that `chmod` no longer had execute permission so I couldn't use it to restore execute permission!

Comment: _"I ran `chmod +x /*`"_ - What output did the command give you?

Comment: What does `ls -l /` say?  Are their any directories *not* owned by root, that you would have even had permission to change?  If no, then your command had no effect, and the safety net of not-running-as-root had the desired effect of stopping this mistake from doing *anything* to the system directories.

Comment: @TripeHound How did you end up fixing it? Booting into a live environment?

Comment: @Cyphase "_Booting into a live environment?_" I suppose _technically_ I did, although the term wasn't known at the time (1993/4). I used a pair of SCO UNIX 3.2 "Recovery" floppies (3½") to boot, from which I could mount the hard-disk. Unfortunately, while the recovery disks had a selection of "useful commands", they didn't include `chmod`. So I had to do something like `cp /bin/ls mychmod` to copy a recovery-disk binary (with execute permission) to a dummy file (still with execute permissions). I then did `cp /dev/hd0/bin/chmod mychmod` to get a file (`mychmod`) [**cont**]

Comment: [**cont**] that had both execute permissions **and** a copy of the `chmod` code. I could then do `mychmod +x /dev/hd0/bin/*` to give everything in the "real" `/bin` directory execute permission (crude, but sufficient to allow the machine to boot). This was all further complicated by the fact that the original incident happened while I was dialed-in (33k modem) to a customer machine... I had to develop the above "rescue" procedure locally, then dictate the instructions over the 'phone to the customer!

Answer (score 16):

That's probably the least harmful accidental chmod-in-root you can do, since it doesn't even recurse. Looking at my Ubuntu box, the only non-directory files in the root directory are vmlinuz and initrd, and an x bit on those shouldn't hurt.

Do a `chmod go-x /root` so the root user's home directory is protected (moderately important if it's a single-user desktop machine), and I think that's about it. (Oh wait, if you weren't even root, you wouldn't even have been able to change permissions on those directories in the first place, so you should be entirely fine.)

Comment: @terdon correct. I was just trying to edit basic files in my home dir, so I wasn't root or anything like that.

Comment: The point is that since you *weren't* running this as root, you should have gotten a `"permission denied"` error from `chmod`. IOW: the accident caused absolutely no damage.